# How to lay out UIImageViews based on the height that is left?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, ios9

I am trying to create this layout, but I am struggeling so badly that I have no words left for it. I have tried for three days but yet I can't create the layout.

I am trying to have the three imageviews in the middle scale if the height of the view changes, but they are not behaving correct. I have successfully manage to get the ratios correct though, but the images either goes behind the blue button, or the blue button suddenly looses its height or the text disappears.

Isn't it possible to have three image views in the middle that **take whatever height is left after the title and text + blue button have been laid out and then properly show them with correct ratios**?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiple approaches here:

1. Size Classes:
   Lay out the views for each possible size (probably the easiest but the least flexible
2. Use Constraints with different priorities:
   You can set a max-height for the image views by adding a constraint for the height and then setting its relationship to equal or less than. This allows the image to scale up until a maximum size is reached.
   Then add a second constraint between the bottom box and the images. Set the priority of this constraint to 750. This makes the image grow in height, when the bottom view moves down.
   Then add another constraint which sets the aspect ratio of the image. If you use the mode of the view to Aspect Fit, the image will now always be scaled up to fit the image view. 

   To make all images scale proportionally, add constraints for equal width and equal height between them, then set the factor to match the proportions between these images. 

   The last step is now to vertically align the images properly as you showed in the pictures. To do that, add constraints between the images, which align them by their vertical centers, bottoms, baselines or tops.